# Can I use DDL commands within a Select Case/If statement using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

For example:

```
SELECT
  col A,
  col B,
  CASE
    WHEN col C = 't'
      THEN (DDL_STATEMENT_Here(Eg:ALTER))
      ELSE (DDL_statement_here(Eg:CREATE))
  END || col D || col E || col F ... etc 
FROM table;
```

Comment: No, you will have to use a store procedure.

Comment: No you cant, *and* you really shouldn't. Try stating the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I have 2 columnar db's - one newly being set up + an old. A default list of schema objects (resource pools, roles, privileges etc) gets set up whenever a new db is created. However, the old db has default + user defined schema objects. Basically, I'm trying to copy these over to the new db (as part of a data migration exercise). I'm trying to write a sql query that will first check if a certain parameter is default (is_default = 't'), in that case alter the schema object, else (is_default = 'f') create all the user defined schema objects (same as old db) in the new db.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to loop through the rows of your table, and perform the DDL for each row. A cursor or a table variable can be used like this,

```
DECLARE @dummy_table TABLE (
    col_c CHAR
    ,rnum INT
    )
DECLARE @rowcount INT = 1
DECLARE @col_c CHAR

INSERT INTO @dummy_table
SELECT [col C]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY [col C]
        ) rnum
FROM TABLE

WHILE (
        SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM @dummy_table
        ) <> 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @col_c = [col C]
    FROM @dummy_table
    WHERE rnum = @rowcount

IF @col_c = 't'
BEGIN
    --ALTER STATEMENT
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --CREATE STATEMENT
END

DELETE
FROM @dummy_table
WHERE rnum = @rowcount
SET @rowcount = @rowcount + 1
END
```